# Dropdown all list and collect data rcurl

Tags: r, rcurl

From a page like this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/11786778/nathalie?tab=reputation
```

How is it possible to dropdown all list from reputation table and receive the information which is loaded in the process of load?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(plyr)

#Doing URLs one by one
url<-"https://stackoverflow.com/users/11786778/nathalie?tab=reputation"

##GET SALES DATA
pricesdata <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//table[1]") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
library(plyr)
df <- ldply(pricesdata, data.frame)
```

Produces:

```
1                                       <NA>
2  Take the result of call for a list of ids
3                                       <NA>
4                                       <NA>
5                                       <NA>
6                       Add Detailed history
7                                       <NA>
8                                       <NA>
9                                       <NA>
10                                      <NA>
11                                      <NA>
12                                      <NA>
13                                      <NA>
14                                      <NA>
15                                      <NA>
16                                      <NA>
17                                      <NA>
18                                      <NA>
19                                      <NA>
20                                      <NA>
21                                      <NA>
22                                      <NA>
23                                      <NA>
24                                      <NA>
25                                      <NA>
26                                      <NA>
27                                      <NA>
28                                      <NA>
29                                      <NA>
30                                      <NA>
31                                      <NA>
32                                      <NA>
33                                      <NA>
34                                      <NA>
35                                      <NA>
36                                      <NA>
37                                      <NA>
38                                      <NA>
39                                      <NA>
40                                      <NA>
41                                      <NA>
42                                      <NA>
43                                      <NA>
>
```